# How do I get the activity that is not null and runOnUIThread() within a Fragment in Kotlin?

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

I need to use threads because there are tasks which can take unknown length of times. I am using a bottom navigation activity and so I have three fragments. Here is the first fragment on load:

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
        ): View? {
               val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_key, container, false)
               Thread(Runnable {
                    // this part does not compile because activity can be null and the
                    // method call should be from non-nullable activity
                    activity.runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable {
                        doSomeTaskHere()   
                    })

               }).start()

              return root
          }
```

How do I pass in the activity from my MainActivity into the fragment that is not-nullable in Kotlin?

Comment: I would suggest moving your logic out of `onCreateView` as that's just for inflating your `Fragment`. You should start your thread in `onActivityCreated` or `onViewCreated`.

Answer (score 0):

For Kotlin, you can either use the `?` operator to "do this only if it's not null" or you can use the `!!` to "do this, I know it won't be null."

For example, you could do:

```
Thread(Runnable {
        // Only run if our activity is not null - this is safe.
        activity?.runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable {
            doSomeTaskHere()   
        })

   }).start()
```

or you could do:

```
Thread(Runnable {
        // I know it won't be null, force run it. If it is null, your app will crash.
        activity!!.runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable {
            doSomeTaskHere()   
        })

   }).start()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Kotlin, you can use coroutine. It is very simple.

```
 GlobalScope.launch {

    doSomeTaskHere() 
 }
```